# If then statement in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
If Label1 = 0 Then
btn1.Enabled = False
ElseIf Label2 = 0 Then
btn2.Enabled = False
ElseIf Label3 = 0 Then
btn3.Enabled = False
ElseIf Label4 = 0 Then
btn4.Enabled = False

End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Right now when it runs after a condition ios true it ends sub.  I want all conditions that are true to execute.  So right now if Label2 = 0 the button is disabled and the program ends.  I want it to continue checking the rest of the Labels.  I'm sure it's an else / If Then issue.

Comment: By the way, your code is using too many "`End If`s". The code as it was posted, requires only one "`End If`"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the ElseIfs.

If you want to test all conditions then test them separately

```
If Label1 = 0 Then
btn1.Enabled = False
End If
If Label2 = 0 Then
btn2.Enabled = False
End If
If Label3 = 0 Then
btn3.Enabled = False
End If
If Label4 = 0 Then
btn4.Enabled = False
End If
```

Comment: End Ifs are required if they statement isn't on the same line as the If Then clause.

Comment: I'm just being nit-picky because you beat me by 30 seconds ;)

Answer (score 3):

Just for the sake of listing, here is another possibility:

```
btn1.Enabled = (Label1 <> 0)
btn2.Enabled = (Label2 <> 0) 
btn3.Enabled = (Label3 <> 0) 
btn4.Enabled = (Label4 <> 0)
```

Comment: ...although this has slightly different behavior.  The original code does nothing to `btnX` if `LabelX <> 0`, whereas this code will enable `btnX`.

Comment: @Cheran - Yeap, definitely you're right. In my personal experience, I never came across a scenario where my answer wouldn't apply, but you've made a very good point.

Answer (score 1):

Only one of those will happen when you use If-Else If conditional block ( it would be the first one that is true ).  If you want each one to happen then use 4 seperate IF conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `ElseIf`: Use Separate `If/Then/End If` structures for all labels.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your code to:

```
If Label1 = 0 Then btn1.Enabled = False
If Label2 = 0 Then btn2.Enabled = False
If Label3 = 0 Then btn3.Enabled = False
If Label4 = 0 Then btn4.Enabled = False

End Sub
```